# Unable to visualise point cloud in RViz even with header.frame_id selected

Tags: rviz, ros-melodic, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, I very new to ROS, so please bear with me. I am trying to render sample point cloud in the RViz, but for some reason it just won't show. I have set fixed frame to `map` which is the value of `header.frame_id`. `rostopic echo` on the point cloud topic returns data, so my take is that the point cloud is correctly generated but cannot be properly displayed in rviz. Here's the code for publishing the point cloud:

```
void Node::PublishMapPoints (std::vector<ORB_SLAM2::MapPoint*> map_points) {
  sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 cloud = MapPointsToPointCloud (map_points);
  map_points_publisher_.publish (cloud);
}

sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 Node::MapPointsToPointCloud (std::vector<ORB_SLAM2::MapPoint*> map_points) {
  if (map_points.size() == 0) {
    std::cout << "Map point vector is empty!" << std::endl;
  }

  sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 cloud;

  const int num_channels = 3; // x y z

  cloud.header.stamp = current_frame_time_;
  cloud.header.frame_id = "map";
  cloud.height = 1;
  cloud.width = map_points.size();
  cloud.is_bigendian = false;
  cloud.is_dense = true;
  cloud.point_step = num_channels * sizeof(float);
  cloud.row_step = cloud.point_step * cloud.width;
  cloud.fields.resize(num_channels);

  std::string channel_id[] = { "x", "y", "z"};
  for (int i = 0; i<num_channels; i++) {
    cloud.fields[i].name = channel_id[i];
    cloud.fields[i].offset = i * sizeof(float);
    cloud.fields[i].count = 1;
    cloud.fields[i].datatype = sensor_msgs::PointField::FLOAT32;
  }

  cloud.data.resize(cloud.row_step * cloud.height);

    unsigned char *cloud_data_ptr = &(cloud.data[0]);

  float data_array[num_channels];
  for (unsigned int i=0; i<cloud.width; i++) {
    if (map_points.at(i)->nObs >= min_observations_per_point_) {
      data_array[0] = map_points.at(i)->GetWorldPos().at<float> (2); //x. Do the transformation by just reading at the position of z instead of x
      data_array[1] = -1.0* map_points.at(i)->GetWorldPos().at<float> (0); //y. Do the transformation by just reading at the position of x instead of y
      data_array[2] = -1.0* map_points.at(i)->GetWorldPos().at<float> (1); //z. Do the transformation by just reading at the position of y instead of z
      //TODO dont hack the transformation but have a central conversion function for MapPointsToPointCloud and TransformFromMat

      memcpy(cloud_data_ptr+(i*cloud.point_step), data_array, num_channels*sizeof(float));
    }
  }

  return cloud;
}
```

Here's my RViz:

[image: image description]

Any help would be much appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/332203/unable-to-visualise-point-cloud-in-rviz-even-with-header.frame_id-selected/) by [mun](https://answers.ros.org/users/44890/mun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2019-09-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-03**:
I'm not sure it really matters, but you seem to be setting `width` and `height`, but not `depth` of your pointcloud. A cloud with a depth of `0` would perhaps not work.

**Comment by [mun](https://answers.ros.org/users/44890/mun/) on 2019-09-03**:
@gvdhoorn I thought I have here: `cloud.data.resize(cloud.row_step * cloud.height);` where `cloud.row_step = cloud.point_step * cloud.width;`. Am I missing something?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-03**:
No. I hadn't had my coffee yet. Ignore my comment.

**Comment by [mun](https://answers.ros.org/users/44890/mun/) on 2019-09-03**:
@gvdhoorn All good. I did hope it could be as straightforward as that though... :(

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-03**:
Btw: I rarely create `PointCloud2` messages by hand. Is there any particular reason you're not creating a regular `pcl::PointCloud<>` and then convert it using `pcl::toROSMsg(..)` (from `pcl_conversions`)?

Also documented [here](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Overview#Publishing_different_point_cloud_types).

**Comment by [mun](https://answers.ros.org/users/44890/mun/) on 2019-09-03**:
@gvdhoorn Oh, I'll try that. I should also add that `rostopic echo` on the map points topic gives data but it's all zeros.

**Comment by [SamsAutonomy](https://answers.ros.org/users/45348/samsautonomy/) on 2019-09-03**:
I definitely agree with @gvdhoorn, it's way easy that way.

Also, when you say it's all zeros, what do you mean? If all of your points are honestly 0,0,0, your point cloud is rather boring and all the points are going to be at the origin. Take a look at your Rviz screenshot, there is one white dot at the origin. Try increasing the point size to 0.1m or something in Rviz and if the white dot at the origin is larger, all of your points are probably sitting at the origin.

**Comment by [mun](https://answers.ros.org/users/44890/mun/) on 2019-09-03**:
I've fixed my code now that they aren't all zeros. I'm getting some variations in the point cloud, but it's clearly not a point cloud. Here's a video: https://youtu.be/Yr9Qsx_Bpns

**Comment by [mun](https://answers.ros.org/users/44890/mun/) on 2019-09-03**:
@gvdhoorn Can I ask why `PointCloud` is preferred over `PointCloud2`?

**Comment by [mun](https://answers.ros.org/users/44890/mun/) on 2019-09-03**:
@gvdhoorn `rostopic echo` can return nonzero data, so the point cloud message is correct, right? The header looks like this:

```
header: 
  seq: 3658
  stamp: 
    secs: 1567488578
    nsecs:  26397067
  frame_id: "map"
height: 1
width: 1194
fields: 
  - 
    name: "x"
    offset: 0
    datatype: 7
    count: 1
  - 
    name: "y"
    offset: 4
    datatype: 7
    count: 1
  - 
    name: "z"
    offset: 8
    datatype: 7
    count: 1
is_bigendian: False
point_step: 12
row_step: 14328
```

Could it be that I've got the scale wrong?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-03**:\

> Can I ask why `PointCloud` is preferred over `PointCloud2`?

The former is a C++ type in the `pcl` library, the latter is a ROS message in the `sensor_msgs` package.

These are two different things.

The `pcl_conversions` package knows how to convert between these two.

> Could it be that I've got the scale wrong?

how could we know? You don't give any information about that.

But just for you to check: *everything* in ROS uses metres for distances. RViz will assume metres in your `PointCloud2` as well.

And again: I would really recommend not creating a `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2` message by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I indeed had the scale wrong. It's all good now! Thanks!

---

Originally posted by [mun](https://answers.ros.org/users/44890/mun/) with karma: 32 on 2019-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0